# Objective-C: Convert float to int64_t without precision loss

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion

**THE SCENARIO** I am working on an application that uses RTPlayer to play prerecorded Video and Audio from our server.

**THE SUSPECTS** RTPlayer has 2 useful properties; `.initialPlaybackTime` and `.currentPosition` for calculating media time position in seconds. `.initialPlaybackTime` sets where in the media the player should start playing from, and `.currentPosition` tells you where you left off to resume at the same position in the media.

**THE ISSUE** The `.initialPlaybackTime` property is of `int64_t` type, and `.currentPosition` is of type `float`. When I "plug" the `.currentPosition` value into `.initialPlaybackTime` there is always about 8-10 seconds **ADDED** to the player's position.

**QUESTION** How can I convert the `.currentPosition` `float` value to a `int64_t` and keep the same value?

Comment: Are you sure `currentPosition` is not wrong? Best to give an example of the float value and then print the int64_t value in your question. If the values are seconds, float and int64_t should be good up to 6 digits with no loss of precision either way. I suspect `currentPosition` is 8-10 second beyond where you think it is for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "8-10 seconds being added to the player's position" may have something to do with the underlying [HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) technology](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/).

If the media you are playing is streamed it is likely that it conforms to this technology and, if so, will be split into several smaller chunks of media (my experience is this is usually about 15 seconds in length for video) at a variety of bitrates.

In that case, unless the `initialPlaybackTime` is set to a value that coincides with the start time of one of those media segments, it is possible the player is just using the nearest media segment and jumping to the beginning of that segment (a common practice) or to the next segment if it is near the end of the current segment to reduce loading a full segment's worth of media data without playing it.

Comment: Much more likely about playlist index than floating point accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thuggish! Actually, we are going to use live streaming as well, however, this particular m3u8 url is just a prerecorded video. Not live streaming. You still think that is the issue?

Comment: @BrandonA You would need to look at the implementation of the `RTPlayer` class or ask the creator about it to know for sure since I doubt its a nuance that is documented. But based on my experience with other players, those are common pitfalls when trying to set an exact starting time in the middle of a media file/steam/etc. Depending on how the pre-recorded video is encoded, the timing may coincide with keyframes in the video data too. There's just a lot of unknowns from a StackOverflow perspective.